# Iterating through folder - handling files that don't fit schema

Tags: error-handling, etl, talend

I have a directory containing multiple xlsx files and what I want to do is to insert the data from the files in to a database.

So far I have solved this by using tFileList -> tFileInputExcel -> tPostgresOutput

My problem begins when one of this files doesn't match the defined schema and returns an error resulting on a interruption of a workflow.

What I need to figure out is if it's possible skip that file (moving it to another folder for instance) and continuing iterating the rest of existing files.

If I check the option "Die on error" the process ends and doesn't process the rest of the files.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by making your initial input schema on the tFileInputExcel be all strings.

After reading the file I would then validate the schema using a tSchemaComplianceCheck set to "Use another schema for compliance check".

You should be able to then connect a reject link from the tSchemaComplianceCheck to a tFileCopy configured to move the file to a new directory (if you want it to move it then just tick "Remove source file").

Here's a quick example:

[image: Job layout]

[image: tSchemaComplianceCheck configuration]

With the following set as the other schema for the compliance check (notice how it now checks that `id` and `age` are Integers):

[image: Proper schema in tSchemaComplianceCheck]

And then to move the file:

[image: tFileCopy configuration]

Your main flow from the tSchemaComplianceCheck can carry on using just strings if you are inserting into a database. You might want to use a tConvertType to change things back to the correct data types after this if you are doing any processing that requires proper data types or you are using your tPostgresOutput component to create the table as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to be close to what I want. 
Clarifies me one more thing plean. in that example, tSchemaComplianceCheck works like a "IF", am I right ? So, if some lines in the file respects the schema they will be inserted in DB.. or not ?

In my case I don't want to insert any line if the file don't match to the schema. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it works like a filter. If the file has any rows that don't match the specified schema then it is rejected and sent to the reject link rather than the main link.

Comment: If the answer helped you then consider accepting the answer and upvoting it so that others with your same problem can more easily find a solution. If it doesn't help you then ask for further help in comments or add detail to your question.